# Open project / ASP.NET solution that are coming from another machine

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I am inexperienced in ASP.NET and I have a problem. I have a project that was created on a machine and I have to maintain it. I copied the project to my current machine and when I try to open the solution / project I get the following visual studio message:

```
http://localhost:52961 : error  : Error opening web http://localhost:52961. Unable to open the Web site 'http://localhost:52961'.  The Web server 'http://localhost:52961' could not be found.
```

Eu tenho o iis instalado e o windows 7, até já tentei criar um novo site localhost:52961 e colocar os arquivos da minha solução lá dentro, mas obtenho erro do iis no browser, a mensagem de erro é:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page can not be accessed because the configuration data related to the page is invalid.
```

I've never really messed with iis and asp.net so I may be committing very wrong things.

Comment: Yes. I have visual studio 2015.

Comment: Is it set to run in IIS Express or local IIS when you look at the project properties? Are you running Visual Studio as an Administrator?

Comment: Are you seeing this error in Visual Studio or Browser?

Comment: In the local IIS. I am running as administrator. The error message I described above appears in Visual Studio. And in the browser another message appears when I access the localhost: 52961.

The message in the browser is: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error. The requested page can not be accessed because the configuration data related to the page is invalid.

Comment: Sorry. The project is set to open on iis express. When I created an equal address in the local iis and started the project in visual studio the following message appeared: localhost:52961 : error : Error opening web localhost:52961. The Web Site 'localhost:52961'; is configured to use IIS Express as the web server but the URL is currently configured on the local IIS web server. To open this Web Site, you must use IIS Manager to remove the bindings using this URL from the local IIS web server.